# Making an iso of windows 10

Tags: 16.04, windows-10, iso, disk-image

i'm using both Windows 10 and Ubuntu, and i'd like to create a disk image of my windows 10 system partition, since its current configuration is satisfying.
Which tool do you know of that could have the Windows 10 eventually be reinstalled and still work ? I know how to use `gnome-disk-utility` to create linux iso, is it the right tools for Windows ?

Comment: You should use the built-in Windows tools to create Windows backups, and use the built-in Linux tools to create Linux backups. Crossing over increases your risk of non-recoverability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"eventually be reinstalled" Not with a tool from Ubuntu. You can create a disk dump of partitions but re-installing from those is not possible. Dumping the disk dump back onto the partition is possible but this is not re-installing. If, for instance, your hardware changed it is a bad idea to restore a disk dump on Windows. Linux is less error prone since we use generic drivers.

Whatever tool you pick it likely is going to be using `dd`.

This

```
dd if=/dev/sdh2 | gzip -c  > /image.img
```

will copy `sdh2` to a compressed file on your root called `image.img.gz`. And

```
gunzip -c /image.img.gz | dd of=/dev/sdh2
```

would put the contents of `/image.img.gz` on sdh2 destroying what is currently on sdh2.

- Make sure there is enough space (and then some) on the destination before doing this.
- Never use `dd` on an active partition.
- Change the location for the image file to /media/$USER/mountpoint/ if you have an USB with enough space to copy the file onto that USB.
- If you use a partition as a destination it is going to be destroyed. If you put the wrong partition as a destination that one is gone if you pick the wrong one. Forever.  A typo of 1 letter or 1 digit in the device name is fatal.
- Always make sure you can restore a backup of your personal data.
- I used sdh2 as a random partition. Change it to your windows partition.

---

When it comes to things like this I would suggest to follow a plan where you can re-install your system from an install medium: I restore my Ubuntu within 15 minutes where I format / and /home (both on an ssd; my /home/$USER has no normal directories) and mount a partition (1Tb hdd) with my files on. That private partition also holds the dirs in /home/$USER/. The hdd now has been inside 3 notebooks (all died for various reasons). To finish my re-install I have a list of commands in a script to add and remove software and to change settings. This method not only works for broken operating systems but also when I would to go to the next version: I only do re-installs.